# NSData contentsOfUrl returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata

I found several similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them solve my problem.

I am trying to get a image from a url. Here's how I do it:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://pic3.zhimg.com/8161ba9638273e0fb1a0201789d22d8e_m.jpg")
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
let image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

But I got an error telling me that `data` is nil.

How can I solve this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here's some screenshots of the error:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your code is perfectly working fine. I think you are getting nil data because of some network issue/restrictions. I checked the same code in my playground and I'm getting the result.

Comment: @MidhunMP I tried it in playground and it worked. But when I run it in `viewDidLoad` of a newly created project I got the same error

Comment: Try with `NSData(contentsOfURL:option:error)`. You may get the error. Could this be related to absence of "https" with iOS9 (and the App Transport Security to set)?

Comment: @Larme Oh yeah! I forgot to add this domain to the info.plist file. Thanks! :)

Comment: seriously...?! do you really want to use a synchronous request on the main thread for fetching an image from external resource? why people never read the docs?! _"Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated."_ ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:))

Comment: @holex I totally forgot about that lol ... you are the real MVP

Comment: @holex thanks for reminding. I will check it out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is probably a result of Apple's new app transport security denying a non-HTTPS request. To work around this you need to modify your app's `Info.plist` file. You can either define an exception for that particular domain

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>pic3.zhimg.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

or disable ATS altogether

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: This page has a helpful image: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33712228/1711103

Answer (score 3):

I think you should, before all, create a resilient code.

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://pic3.zhimg.com/8161ba9638273e0fb1a0201789d22d8e_m.jpg")
{ 
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) 
    {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data) 
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```