# NSData returns nil, why?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata

Try to download a piece of data from internet with the following line:

```
var totalData: NSData?
totalData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
```

where url is

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Annie+Hall&y=&plot=short&r=json
```

but `totalData` become nil. Any idea why? It happens only in Xcode 7, not before.

Comment: Use the `NSData` initializer that also takes options and an error. Then you can log the resulting error to see the cause of the issue.

Comment: This is becoming an annoyingly common question.

Comment: A better duplicate might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567710/nsdata-contentsofurl-returns-nil

Comment: It is not Xcode, it is iOS and the version.