# How to load UIImage from url?

Tags: swift, url, uiimage

I have the following problem:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
@IBOutlet weak var DetailImageView1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var DetailLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var DetailLabel2: UILabel!

var SentData1: String!
var SentData2: String!
var SentData3: NSURL!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    DetailLabel.text = SentData1
    DetailLabel2.text = SentData2
    let url = NSURL(string: "\(SentData3)")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    DetailImageView1.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

I am taking the picture from a url and segue the url link from my previous view controller to this one. Then I created SentData3: NSURL! 
Now I have to show the picture in the DetailImageView1.image, but when I try to test the app I get an error.

I would be glad if someone can show me the mistake.

Comment: Stop using the crash operator (`!`)

Comment: Which line is crashing?  What is `SentData1`, `SentData2`, and `SentData3` being initialized to?

Comment: Try to declare `SentData3` as optional as follows: `var SentData3 : NSURL?`

Comment: but when I delete it, I get a message please insert !

Comment: It is crashing here :    DetailImageView1.image = UIImage(data: data!)

Comment: I tried with ? same error again

Comment: It seems that you are getting crash because the image file is not at the specified url. Is it. Cross check the url and try to load in your web browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSData contentsOfUrl returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567710/nsdata-contentsofurl-returns-nil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that for SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RemoteImage: View {
private enum LoadState {
    case loading, success, failure
}

private class Loader: ObservableObject {
    var data = Data()
    var state = LoadState.loading

    init(url: String) {
        guard let parsedURL = URL(string: url) else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL: \(url)")
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: parsedURL) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data, data.count > 0 {
                self.data = data
                self.state = .success
            } else {
                self.state = .failure
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

@StateObject private var loader: Loader
var loading: Image
var failure: Image

var body: some View {
    selectImage()
        .resizable()
}

init(url: String, loading: Image = Image(systemName: "photo"), failure: Image = Image(systemName: "multiply.circle")) {
    _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader(url: url))
    self.loading = loading
    self.failure = failure
}

private func selectImage() -> Image {
    switch loader.state {
    case .loading:
        return loading
    case .failure:
        return failure
    default:
        if let image = UIImage(data: loader.data) {
            return Image(uiImage: image)
        } else {
            return failure
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then use it in your view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
let jsonURL = "https://cf.geekdo-images.com/thumb/img/sD_qvrzIbvfobJj0ZDAaq-TnQPs=/fit-in/200x150/pic2649952.jpg"

var body: some View {
    RemoteImage(url: jsonURL)
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 200)
}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This works for me...

```
var image: UIImage?
let urlString = "https://example.com/filename"

let url = NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL
if let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
    image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
}
```

..."image", will either be nil if there was an error, or it will contain the new UIImage object.

Answer (score 0):

If SentData3 is already a URL, you can just simply insert it. Don't force unwrap a variable when you are not sure whether it will return nil or not.

```
if let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: SentData3) {
    DetailImageView1.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

Comment: What value is in your SentData3? Is it a https url or http url?

Comment: Do your mind showing what error you are having as well?